# touchMove event update frequency low/stutters/lags/janky on mobile device

Tags: javascript

I'm facing an issue where the `touchMove` event listener on a div is not running frequent enough with causes the drag action to lag:

I can not understand why this example lags
https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-elion-sxqe4?file=/src/App.js

Run the app on mobile: https://sxqe4.csb.app/

**And this does not:**
https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/fjmn0pej/

These examples are both very trivial in terms of complexity

I've measured the time between `touchmove` invocations and it's around 200ms (7ms on desktop). That's why it's janky on mobile but I see no reason why it should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is an issue with the current version of mobile chrome.